# Typescript React <Select> onChange handler type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to add an onChange event handler to the Select component from material-ui:

```
<Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={values.country}
      onChange={handleCountryChange}
    >
      {countries.map(c => {
        return (
          <MenuItem value={c}>{c}</MenuItem>
        )
      })}
    </Select>
```

and my event handler:

```
const handleCountryChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setValues({...values, country: event.target.value});
  };
```

but I get the following error:

> Type '(event: ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown; }>, child: ReactNode) => void'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Since MUI Select in not a real select element you will need to cast `e.target.value` using `as Type` and type the handler as `React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>`

```
const handleCountryChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
  setValues({...values, country: event.target.value as string});
};
```

Comment: Even this is not working. src/core/content/content.component.tsx
  Line 67:37:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon.

  65 |
  66 |   const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
> 67 |     const value = event.target.value as string[];
     |                                     ^
  68 |     debugger;
  69 |     setDataLines(value);
  70 |   };

Comment: yes its not working

Answer (score 28):

This is proper for the latest MUI 5 / Select

```
  import { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material";

   const handleOnChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>) => {
    const value = event.target.value as YourEnumType;
  };
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I see `SelectChangeEvent` defined as ```export type SelectChangeEvent<T = string> =
  | (Event & { target: { value: T; name: string } })
  | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;```

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: I had to do something like this: `const handleThingChanged = (event: ChangeEvent<{ name?: string, value: unknown}>): void => {`

Comment: Something very close to this worked for me. Importing event type definitions from Mui seems like the way to go. `const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>) => {
    onMoodChange(event.target.value);
  };`

Comment: Woof, this worked for me, but it's ridiculous that you have to use `<unknown>` that way. I tried the solution from @AleshHoudek's comment, which at least makes a lot more sense, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

None of these are correct IMO. Casting "as" should generally be avoided since you'll lose the type checking you get from letting the code infer the type. It's also weird to explicitly type it as `unknown` only to later cast it to a string. Ideally you'd use a typeguard if you truly didn't know. To be clear, if somehow `event.target.value` is actually a boolean and we're casting it to a string here we won't know until the app throws a bug later down the line.

The docs (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/) have this as the onChange signature:

```
function(event: SelectChangeEvent<T>, child?: object) => void

event: The event source of the callback. You can pull out the new value by accessing event.target.value (any). 

Warning: This is a generic event not a change event unless the change event is caused by browser autofill.

child: The react element that was selected when native is false (default).
```

So with that in mind it becomes:

```
const handleCountryChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
  setValues({...values, country: event.target.value });
};
```

We don't need to define T here explicitly as a string because it's a string by default. HTML inputs read in as strings.

Answer (score 3):

Had that issue while using Material UI. Didn't know they had their own types

```
import { SelectChangeEvent } from '@mui/material/Select';

const changeSymbol = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        console.log(event)
}
```

Comment: Best answer!
Should be chosen as a default.

Answer (score 1):

Seemed counterintuitive for me either, but I had to do this:

```
const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<{ value: string | unknown }>) => formik.setFieldValue('field', e.target.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

im using
import Select from '@mui/joy/Select';
import Option, { optionClasses } from '@mui/joy/Option';

all the solutions from the above didn't work

this did work

const handleChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent> | React.KeyboardEvent | React.FocusEvent<Element, Element> | null, value: any) => {
setSort(value);
};

Comment: Make sure to format everything correctly, using code formatting, ponctuation and all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where it's documented, but the Select module also exports SelectChangeEvent.  This is what I used to get it:

import Select, {SelectChangeEvent} from '@mui/material/Select';

```
    const handleGenerationSelectChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>, child: React.ReactNode) => {
    let genHolder = currentGeneration;
    genHolder.source = event.target.value as string;
    setCurrentGeneration({...genHolder});
};
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems the definition for the change event is incorrect in the `SelectInput.d.ts`. More here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15400#issuecomment-484891583

Try to use their recommended signature:

```
const handleCountryChange = (event: any) => { ... }
```

Comment: this is not their recommended signature, that's a lazy `any` ahahah